# Is there an English translation of Die wichtigsten Instanzen gegen die Graf-Wellhausensche Hypothese?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, translation, english

Is there an English translation of Die wichtigsten Instanzen gegen die Graf-Wellhausensche Hypothese? This is the book in German by R' Dovid Tzvi Hoffman זצ''ל, disproving the documentary hypothesis.

Comment: Hebrew translation is available here (if that helps) http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/reayot/tohen-2.htm

Comment: @JoelK Thanks! This helps

Answer (score 1):

A fully annotated English translation can be downloaded for free on McGill University's site, [here](https://escholarship.mcgill.ca/concern/theses/m326m3865?locale=en). It's not the best quality, though (the letters are somewhat "broken"). Scroll down to "actions" and select "download". The first half is an introduction. The translation of the work starts on pg. 118.